# /me/inbox is not returning most recent items

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, inbox

Looks like /me/inbox is either a bit behind or it's not supposed to be realtime.

Explanation: for a comment that I received 4 hours ago
[image]

It's not returned in the API:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox#page=1&pagesize=100&filter=!6P-iTlM)-Mu*B&site=stackoverflow&run=true
```

[image]

Is this by design? and if so, is there an upper limit estimate to how long would it take (e.g. one day max)?

---

**UPDATE**

I got a new notification and it's actually appearing in the API response, yet the one reported previously is still missing (the one with link: `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/46914097?noredirect=1`):

[image]
[image]